# How do you set a static IP that is already leased to someone else by DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, static-ip

## Summary

I am on a network with many devices. When I use `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to set a static IP address that is currently available (not leased by the DHCP server), it works just fine. However, when I try to set a static IP address that is already leased, it won't work.

## Question

**How can I set the static IP of my Raspberry Pi to an address that is already taken?**

## More details

I added the following lines to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth1
    static ip_address=192.168.203.97/24
```

Then I rebooted the device. After rebooting, I ran `ifconfig` and saw this output:

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.203.97  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.203.255
        inet6 ...
        ...
```

So I successfully set a static IP address of 192.168.203.97 .

After that, I tried to change `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to this:

```
interface eth1
    static ip_address=192.168.203.39/24
```

I then rebooted and saw this from `ifconfig`:

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 ...
        ...
```

Notice that there is no `inet` at all. I could not set the static IP address to 192.168.203.39 .

I can tell from `nmap` that 192.168.203.39 is being used by another device on the network. Meanwhile, 192.168.203.97 is not.

## Edit: Even More Details

The use case here is that the Raspberry Pi is the main computer of a networked device. The pi will be running some application code that allows a user to interact with the device. One such interaction involves changing the device's network settings, like IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway. These should be configurable to anything the user wants to set them to.

If the user wants to set a static IP address for their device, they should be able to do that regardless of whatever their DHCP server is doing.

Comment: Why not just use the address that isn't assigned? Trying to reassign an IP address will likely just move the IP issue to the other machine.

Comment: I understand it's a bit silly to assign an address that's already in use. However, for my application the use case does exist. I am developing a networked device, and a user might for example set the static IP of the device, then physically move it and plug into another network and expect the IP to be the same, not assigned by the new network's DHCP server. It's up to the network administrator to make sure that they are setting the static IPs in a sane way. But the device should still be able to set its own static IP to any valid address. That being said, I could be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Traditionally a static IP is set in the client device from **outside** the dynamic IP pool. It is a very bad idea to set a static IP address within the dynamic IP pool. The DHCP server  (typically the router) does not care that you have assigned `192.168.203.39` to your Raspberry Pi and may assign that IP to another device when a new device asks for an IP address from the pool. Just imagine what will happen if that new device happens to be your boss's laptop! Goodluck explaining to him why he can't get online!

Comment: It is up to the network administrator to set aside a range of IP addresses outside the DHCP dynamic address pool. Then the network admin will have to tell you which of those static IP addresses are not assigned to any device, and you can use for your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What you said makes sense. However, the way users of my device set up their networks is not under my control. I simply need to create a system that is capable of setting its own static IP address.

Comment: What you are asking for is to break the network.  The dhcp server will not give you an address that is currently in use because two computers can not use the same ip address and still function on the network.

Comment: Just so you know, setting your address to a static address another computer is using is something that makes network administrators angry enough to come and yank your network cord out of the wall and ban you from connecting your device to the network.   If you aren't the network administrator and don't have control of the network, Don't do that.

Comment: So you want to break your user's network, not the best business plan.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I added an edit with some more information. What I am looking for here is either an answer to the question at hand or a specific reason why the thing I am trying to do is impossible. @ user10489 this setting **is** for network admins. @ Steve Robillard no. @ user68186 (deleted comment) I already am using avahi, and I already have functions for users to set their own hostname as well. Using DHCP and connecting via the hostname is the normal use case.

Comment: "If the user wants to set a static IP address for their device, they should be able to do that *regardless of whatever their DHCP server is doing*." The user can already set a static IP address, but they must do so after considering what their DHCP server is doing.

Comment: @user68186 "The user can already set a static IP address." No they can't because based on the example in the question, it doesn't work in all cases. That's the exact problem. Of course if they want their network to function properly, they need to consider IP collisions, as does anybody who is dealing with static IP addresses. But in this case, they physically cannot set the address. The documented way of setting the static address does not work here, so it cannot be set. Either there is an alternate way to set it (what I am looking for), or it's not possible.

Comment: Documented way is the way. It works if you and your customers follow the networking rules. It is not possible if you don't follow the rules. It is as simple as that.

Comment: *"If the user wants to set a static IP address for their device, they should be able to do that regardless of whatever their DHCP server is doing."*  This is along the lines of "drivers should be allowed to do whatever they want regardless of the state of traffic lights, signage, and what other drivers are doing".  It implies either you do not understand how vehicle traffic works and is made possible, or that you wish to disrupt this system and cause an accident.

Comment: @goldilocks yes, that's a great analogy. I'm asking "how do I build a steering wheel that works?" and these comments are replying "make sure to stay in your lane while steering." I am very well aware of the fact that this use case is non-standard. However, I'm not trying to build a train; I'm trying to build a car -- a machine that lets its driver steer it where they want. Ford doesn't make cars that prevent drivers from going off the road. Anyway, let's end this discussion here and keep the comments minimal going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are actively breaking the network, all possible solutions will circumvent any safety. For `dhcpcd`, using the `--noarp` option will prevent DHCP to claim the IP address with ARP, which might be sufficient.

```
dhcpcd -S ip_address=192.168.203.97/24 \
-S routers=192.168.203.1 \
-S domain_name_servers=192.168.203.1 \
--noarp \
eth0
```

Once again: YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THIS! You will disrupt the network access of the person that got the IP address from the DHCP server. Furthermore, in normal operation, your client will want to run the `dhcpcd` without all the extra options, i.e. as standard.

An example of how you could do this would be to create a separate network. You could use a VirtualBox to access this network. Use an USB-network adapter, that you forward to the VirtualBox as USB device. You then have a network that is completely separate from the normal production network.

Comment: This seems to point in the right direction, so thank you. However, it also disables IPv4LL, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Of course it does. With IPv4LL or APIPA, network hosts select a random candidate address within the reserved range and use Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) probes to ascertain that the address is not in use on the network. You want to use addresses that are in use, so you will need to disable the protocols that do the duplicate address checking and prevention.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command, arp -a , this grabs all of the MAC addresses on a network and associated IP addresses.  Since MAc addresses are unique to each device, you can insure you are finding the device you want, even when you don't know the IP address.  Use GREP to filter your result or other flags on the arp command to get what you want.

Note that the initial characters in a MAC address are associated with the devices' manufacturer (or at least the network module's manufacturer) to help you find the targeted devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it doesn't address the question. Any thoughts on the question?

Comment: I had mistakenly assumed that you want static addresses so other devices on the network can always find them. If you are just fantasizing about infinite configurability, then, you're on your own because you're trying to drive anywhere in the road - regardless of the rules when  everyone else is following the rules.  If you look around and see that everyone else on earth has managed to meet their goals with the rules set, you have to decide if you are either an "innovator" or if you are not understanding the technology.

Comment: Pretty sure I am not understanding the technology.